# What does "one of reinvention" mean?

Tags: meaning

> My life in Japan has coincided with the start of my education as a
>   writer. Although my ideal future as a novelist is **one of reinvention**,
>   and although I won't be in this place for good, I think this place
>   will be in me for good.

I know what reinvent means but in this particular case I have some troubles with understanding. Can it be replaced with something like "... my ideal future as a novelist is about starting something new"?

Comment: "Reinvention" is a buzzword that has become popular in the past 20 years or so, meaning to change the course of ones life (or change, say, the orientation of a corporation) such that you're a "new" person (or corporation), with goals, interests, and behaviors different from before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my ideal future as a novelist is about starting something new"?

Exactly. A "future of reinvention" in this context means **"a future of originality"** which, for a writer, is a marker of greatness.